# Compatibility issue with IE 11 and JAWS for role="presentation" while trying to read tables?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader

I have multiple tables where I am trying to read the rows together. Here is an example table:

```html
<table class="data-table" role="presentation">
  <tr role="rowgroup">
    <td role="gridcell">
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell">
      John Doe
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="rowgroup">
    <td role="gridcell">
      <strong>Size</strong>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell">
      XL
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="rowgroup">
    <td role="gridcell">
      <strong>Color</strong>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell">
      blue
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this rendered example, This should read the first the full row "Name - John Doe". It works as intended on Chrome but fails to read the full row with IE11. Is there a reason why that is happening?

Edit, I looked into it further and it seems to happen if the table is wraped with a  tag. Not sure why it is happening but at least I can repoduce the issue more consistently.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on my side. I have tried to create a sample using your code, it seems that the table render success in IE11 and chrome. Please explain more details about the problem. Besides, please try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there contains some error?

Comment: The table displays correctly on both browsers. But it not announced as intended. Is it possible that it is a part of the settings?

Answer (score 1):

This markup is quite complex and I'm not sure what you're aiming to achieve.
This seems like a data table to me. Could you remove the `role="presentation"` so that the table is exposed to AT as a data table, then mark the first column up as `<th>` column headers, and the second column as `<td>` cells? That way you don't need to try and control what the screenreader says and when, and you're using semantic markup.
Most screenreader users know how to interact with data tables to extract the information they need, and trying to mask this interaction and control the user experience is unlikely to work out well.
Trust your users :-)